# Should we have tags for 'sub features' of org mode?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just introduced the [publish](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publish) tag in an edit of [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/551/how-to-have-org-publish-automatically-publish-generated-images), and was wondering if that's something we want. Do we want to have tags for 'sub features' of e.g. org-mode. If so, should those tags be like [publish](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publish) or [org-publish](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org-publish) (or something similar)?

Quickly looking through the tags I noticed one question using the [export](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/export) tag, for which this also holds.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely prefix the tags with *org-*.

[org-export](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org-export) and [org-publish](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org-publish) have an obvious meaning.
[export](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/export) means nothing to me at first (in the context of emacs).

I also see no problem in applying both tags [org-export](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org-export) and [org-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org-mode). It might seem a bit redundant, but both tags do apply and that is how tags work. Both people who follow [org-export](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org-export) and [org](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org) should see this question.

### Update

I noticed we also have a [ox-html](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ox-html) tag. That might be starting to get a little too specific.

Comment: Regarding the update.  I would limit it to `org-export` with regards to exporting issues `ox-*`.  `org-publish` is a subset of `org-export` but with it's own issues at times.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say go with something along the lines of [org-feature](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org-feature).  That is how they have been dealt with on SO.